# MySQL query log equivalent for Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

MySQL has the option to log are queries executed towards the database.
Microsoft SQL server has the same option, by using the SQL Server Profiler. However, I'm using JPA (Hibernate) as ORM tool and I can see queries are transformed to stored procedures.

I can see a lot of the following lines:

```
exec sp_execute 6, 8
exec sp_execute 7, 8
exec sp_execute 4, 8
```

... which makes it hard to debug the SQL statements (as I have to look for the corresponding stored procedure)

Any idea's how to quickly see the real SQL queries?

Thanks!
Jochen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DMVs to have a look at recently run queries, this will give you the queries that have executed in the last day, I think this should give you more detail on the query text too:

```
SELECT        SQLTEXT.text, STATS.last_execution_time
FROM          sys.dm_exec_query_stats STATS
CROSS APPLY   sys.dm_exec_sql_text(STATS.sql_handle) AS SQLTEXT
WHERE         STATS.last_execution_time > GETDATE()-1
ORDER BY      STATS.last_execution_time DESC
```

You can obviously change the where clause to get the date range that you are interested in.

Comment: steoleary: thanks, this is a start. By tweaking the WHERE clause, I could find the quer(y)(ies) I was looking for. Too bad the actual value of parameters is not available (which is logical, as they are passed to the Stored Procedure)